# Diagonal minors of matrix

Tags: matrix

I need to calculate the minor of a matrix. I am going to use *Mathematica* example here,

```
(mat = Table[i^2 + i j + j^3, {i, 4}, {j, 4}]) // MatrixForm;

Minors[mat, 3, Identity] // MatrixForm;

Minors[mat] // MatrixForm;
```

Since I am going to calculate the minors of big matrices and I only need to know the diagonal elements, is there a way just to calculate the diagonal elements in minor matrix?

Comment: Can't you use `Diagonal` instead of `Identity` in your second example ?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** You can also use `Part`

```
Det[mat[[#, #]]] & /@ Reverse[Subsets[Range[Length@mat] , {3}]]
(* {-36, -288, -252, -24} *)

Grid[{MatrixForm@#, Det@#} & /@ (mat[[#, #]] & /@ 
    Reverse[Subsets[Range[Length@mat] , {3}]]), Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Determinants of `2X2` submatrices on the diagonal:

```
Grid[{MatrixForm@#, Det@#} & /@ (mat[[#, #]] & /@ 
    Reverse[Subsets[Range[Length@mat] , {2}]]), Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

```
mat = Table[i^2 + i j + j^3, {i, 4}, {j, 4}]

Det[Drop[mat, {#}, {#}]] & /@ Range[Length@mat]
{-36, -288, -252, -24}
```

Timings for random `100X100` real and integer matrices:

```
tstmat = RandomReal[100, {100, 100}];
(res1 = Det[Drop[tstmat, {#}, {#}]] & /@ Range[Length@tstmat]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.156253 *)
(res2 = Diagonal@Minors[tstmat]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.596787 *)
res1 == Reverse@res2
(* True *)

tstmat2 = RandomInteger[100, {100, 100}];
(res1 = Det[Drop[tstmat2, {#}, {#}]] & /@ Range[Length@tstmat2]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.234382 *)
(res2 = Diagonal@Minors[tstmat2]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 125.368340 *)
res1 == Reverse@res2
(* True *)
```

Comment: Hi Kguler, Thanks for replying me back, it seems a efficient way, I am trying to apply it for my own program where I need to calculate the Minors[mat,k] where k changes from zero to the size of mat. Where k=3, i will get what you have described above, but for k=2, now the Minors matrix becomes 6x6 matrix(4!/(2! (4 - 2)!)). How I can I use Drop function to avoid calculating the off-diagonal element of minors?

Comment: @setareh, please see the update.

Comment: Hi  kguler, I am trying to use this method to run my code,

Answer (score 1):

```
Diagonal @ Minors[mat]
```

(*
{-24, -252, -288, -36}
*)

Comment: "Since I am going to calculate the minors of big matrices and I only need to know the diagonal elements, is there a way just to calculate the diagonal elements in minor matrix?" — Surely, performance is an issue here.